# How do I find the position in the document that is visible in a QTextBrowser?

Tags: qt, qtextbrowser, qtextcursor

When the user scrolls in a `QTextBrowser` in my application, I want to retrieve the position in the document that they've scrolled to (offset in the document, not the GUI position.)

If I can make the cursor jump to that location, I can get `QTextCursor.position()`. But I don't see a way to make the cursor jump to the visible location in the browser. The cursor stays where it is when I scroll.

Comment: Use the position of the vertical scrollbar.

Comment: If you have an alternative solution then please post it in the answer space. Questions should contain only the problem statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not completely understand the description of your problem, but maybe you can determine the cursor (i.e. the position in text document) of the beginning and the end of the visible area by calling https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#cursorForPosition

```
QRect rect = textBrowser->rect();
QTextCursor firstVisible = textBrowser->cursorForPosition(rect.topLeft());
QTextCursor lastVisible = textBrowser->cursorForPosition(rect.bottomRight());
```

I have not tested it, but I think you get the idea. Maybe you will need to use the rect of `textBrowser->viewport()` instead of the rect of `textBrowser`. You need to experiment a bit with this to find what works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Based on V.K.'s answer, here is my solution in Python:

```py
browserRect = self.mainText.rect()
newCursor = self.mainText.cursorForPosition(browserRect.topLeft())
self.mainText.setTextCursor(newCursor)
textPos = mainText.textCursor().position()
```

Actually, just using `QPoint(0,0)` probably would work just as well, since the upper left of the browser's rectangle is pretty close to (0,0).